# How to avoid 3rd parties libraries to be included into 'vendor.js' on 'ng- build? I want to use CDN instead

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6, ng-build

I'm working on Angular 6 app using Angular-CLI.
When I make `ng build` compiling generate also a `vendor.js` file which includes all libraries I installed with NPM. That's ok for Angular framework itself due to build process perform some optimizations on which modules are used.

For external libraries (eg. moment, highcharts, etc) I don't want them into this vendor files. I want to load them using CDN.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You could directly include links in your `index.html` file. For instance, with momentjs

**index.html**

```
<script src="http://yourcdn.com/moment.min.js"/>
```

And in your component, replace

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

with

```
declare let moment: any;
```

But this means that you cannot use the typed variables when using that lib in your component

Comment: yeah, I tried it before, but as you wrote, there's no types support. Is there any way to install just @types but to continue using CDN?

Comment: I haven't tried, but this should be possible. Maybe something like `declare let moment : Moment;` after installing moment's types. Note: moment do provide their own types, but I'm not sure whether you can use them